# Change IDLE cursor to block?

Tags: python

I am using the python IDLE 2.7.1.1

I want to change the cursor from the blinking line (`|`) to a block when using IDLE. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean switch from insert mode to replace mode?

Comment: @Tagc i mean the same mode , with just the cursor changed to block rather than the vertical line

Comment: @Rojan Pressing insert does not affect the appearance of the cursor (tested in Python IDLE 2.7.10 on Windows 7).

Comment: @Tagc I just tried, you're right

Comment: IDLE is open source and apparently contains logic to control the appearance of the cursor (insert vs overwrite mode)—so I suggest you take a look at the source and see if there's any way to override what it does.